# Log for an application's activity when it is created and test using Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, logging

I use Visual Studio C++ 2010 to read a source code, understand it and modify it. I found it would be very helpful if one has a log file after the application is "compiled and run". The log file must record the following stuff: which function are excuted (in order), an "if" statement is true or false (better if it can list the truth of false of all its component). Is there such a function in Visual Studio or a plugin to do such thing?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are asking for a complete runtime code flow and semantic analysis. As far as I know there is no tool that can do this. Tools for static code analysis are available but this is not what you want. IntelliTrace is not an option because it does not support C++. A code coverage tool might help you partially. But the best way to analyze code flow is currently setting breakpoints and analyzing the callstack. Imagine how hard it would be for the tool you would like to have to build you a correct log (maybe a flowchart?) for multiple threads.